# Highlight checkbox

Tags: jquery, css, highlight

I have radio buttons within a table. When clicked, I would like the neighboring cell to turn green.
 I was able to achieve this using JQuery to add a "highlight" class on $.change event.

My problem is that sometimes the page loads with "checked" attribute already set. How can I use JQuery to locate all radio button elements that already have a "checked" attribute when the page loads? Here's what I tried, but doesn't seem to be working.

JQUERY

```
$('input:radio').ready(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).parent().addClass('highlight');
        var $td = $(this).parent();
        $td.siblings().removeClass('highlight');
        $td.next().addClass('highlight');
    }   
});
```

CSS

```
#sort td.highlight {background: #33FF99;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through all the radio buttons use the `each` function:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').each(function(i,e) {
        if($(e).is(':checked')){
            $(e).parent().addClass('highlight');
            var $td = $(e).parent();
            $td.siblings().removeClass('highlight');
            $td.next().addClass('highlight');
        }
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var check = $('input:radio:checked');

    if (check.is(':checked')) {
        $(check).parent('td').addClass('highlight');
    }

    $('input:radio').on('change', function () {
        $('#sort td').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).parent('td').addClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/cn073npq/2/

Comment: This does not solve the problem when "checked" is set by default on page load. This only adds the "highlight" class when a change is made. I need to add it for radios that are already checked when the page loads too.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a utility function to highlight the next cell. Call this function on `document.ready` for each radio in the table. Call the same function on `change` event of each radio.

Some thing like this:

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/tee56wz0/***

***Demo Snippet***:

```js
$("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
    setHighlight(this);  // call the utility function for each radio on document.ready
});

$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {
    setHighlight(this);  // call the utility function for each radio on change
});

function setHighlight(elem) {
    if (elem.checked) {  // if the radio is checked, 
        $("table td").removeClass('highlight');        // remove highlight from all cells
        $(elem).parent().next().addClass("highlight"); // add highlight to next cell
    }
}
```

```css
td.highlight {background: #33FF99;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="common" /></td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="common" checked /></td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="common" /></td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="common" /></td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need write common click event for the radio button
it will check for the immediate next td/div and adds the class to it

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("click", function() {
    $("td").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().next().addClass("active");
});
```

if HTML code looks like this

```
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="common" /></td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="common" checked /></td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="common" /></td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="common" /></td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS class to add color as background to the td

```
.active {background: #00FF00;}
```